# Spring Boot Astra Cassandra - keyspace specified in application.yml but still throws error "No keyspace has been specified"

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-astra

I am trying to build a very simple api connecting to an astra Cassandra nodal database with spring boot. However, even when I have specified the keyspace in application.yml, it still throws the exception:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename
```

Here is my application.yml:

```
astra.api:
  application-token: <my-token>
  database-id: <my-db-id>
  database-region: <my-db-region>

astra.cql:
  enabled: true
  downloadScb.path: secure-connect.zip

spring.data.cassandra:
  keyspace-name: shopping_list
  schema-action: CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
```

I have also tried using `keyspace` instead of `keyspace-name`, and putting it under astra.api or even astra.cql. None of these works, though.

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-nosql-database) exactly but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

I have checked the token, database-id and database-region are all correct and the secure connect bundle is also there. The application can indeed get the other values from application.yml such as the scb path and schema-action but apparently not keyspace-name.

Thanks a lot for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `astra-spring-boot-starter` (with all key `astra.*`) will initialize `CqlSession` and any connection needed for Astra (Cassandra, Rest Apis, gRPC, pulsar...).

Spring Data Casandra detects the connection and uses it. You can use any configuration key of the Cassandra driver below `driver-config`.

The `application.yaml` should look like.

```
astra:
  api:
    application-token: <your_token>
    database-id: <your_db_id>
    database-region: <your_db_region>
  cql:
    enabled: true
    download-scb: 
    enabled: true
    driver-config:
      basic:
        session-keyspace: <your_keyspace>
```

Documentation of the starter
https://github.com/datastax/astra-sdk-java/wiki/Spring-Boot-Starter-Quickstart#4-configuration

Sample working project (mvc, rest, cassandra, Oauth2, thymeleaf)
https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-betterreads

Comment: Thank you so much! I have found like 10 different configurations from different websites and YouTube videos for the application.yaml (or application.properties) but this is the only one that actually works.

Comment: How do we add multiple keyspaces here ? as our application grew, we are thinking of using different keyspaces for each module. @clunven

Comment: Spring Data does not easily allow multiple keyspaces, you need to override template and session factory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770043/multiple-keyspace-support-for-spring-data-cassandra-repositories it is also a code smell as that probably means you need to break your monolithic (different keyspaces = different RF and DCs). You can also prefix your query with ks name: SELECT * from KS2.table